# QWebkit (Qt 4.8.5) on Mac OS X won't play Adobe Flash

Tags: macos, flash, qt, qt4, pyqt

I'm running a little low on ideas about how to run flash animations in Qt (currently 4.8.5) on Apple Mac OS X (Lion). A simple snippet like the one that follows works smoothly both on windows and linux, loading the plugin just fine:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {      
  QApplication app(argc, argv);  
  QUrl url("http://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about");

  // Set specific QWebView settings
  QWebSettings *defaultSettings = QWebSettings::globalSettings();
  defaultSettings->setAttribute(QWebSettings::JavascriptEnabled, true);
  defaultSettings->setAttribute(QWebSettings::PluginsEnabled, true);

  webview = new QWebView();
  webview->setGeometry(0,0,640,450);
  webview->load(url);                    
  webview->show();

  return app.exec();
}
```

I tried pretty much everything and after a thorough research on this topic these are the steps I followed with no luck:

- homebrew install (compiled OK as a 64bit binary, but flash won't play)
- homebrew install -universal (compiling sadly failed)
- downloaded qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.5 off digia and compiled as arch i386 since I read the flash plugin supposedly requires a patch to run as a 64bit library, even though there's NO issue whatsoever in chromium (not chorme) and safari (qt compiled and installed OK as a 32bit binary in /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.5/, qmake worked great, but flash won't play)
- tried several older flash plugins by removing and reinstalling the files in /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/ since you never know with flash... (didn't change a thing, no luck)
- tried stripping the various versions of Flash Player.plugin of the x86_64 version with ditto --arch in order to show up just as a 32bit plugin (again, no luck)

My question is: is there ANYBODY that was ever able to run flash animations with Qt 4 and QWebkit on Mac OS X? If so, would anybody care to share his exact steps?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is an incompatibility between Qt 4.8.x and the latest version of the flash plugin on OSX.

We opened an issue on Qt's Jira track system at https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-32931, but it's still unresolved, and there's a duplicate of this question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18142978/latest-flash-player-for-os-x-not-working-with-qt-4-8-n-applications.

Qt 5.x is working fine, anyway, so if you don't really need to stay on Qt4, just switch on the latest version of Qt and the same code should work.